# webview_flutter migration V4 Doc

Tags: flutter, webview, migration, code-documentation

How do I make my current code compatible with V4 update I checked [their documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) but
I couldn't follow along

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();

WebView(
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
       navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {}
        onProgress: (progress) {},
        gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
      ),
```

Comment: a lot of documentation is missing and it's a struggle to migrate. hope everything else worked as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved :

```
  WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

    controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.url))
  ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
    onProgress: (progress) {
      if (progress >= 100) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    },
  ));

 WebViewWidget(controller: controller)
```